# SFML Touch position is not correct

Tags: c++, events, touch, sfml, rectangles

I am testing a touch in sfml on android using app called cxx droid. My code set's the RectangleShape where i press. But even when i make the position relative to window its not relative to it. I touch in place shape's pos in another place!

My Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

Font font;

int main() {
    
    font.loadFromFile("font.otf");
    
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(500,700),"My window",Style::Titlebar | Style::Close);
    
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    
    RectangleShape shape(Vector2f(300,40));
    
    while(window.isOpen()) {
        
        window.setView(window.getDefaultView());
        
        Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == event.Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        
        if(Touch::isDown(0)) {
        shape.setPosition(Touch::getPosition(0,window).x,Touch::getPosition(0,window).y);
        }

        
        window.clear(Color::Green);
        
        window.draw(shape);
        
        window.display();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the top left corner of the shape is at the position you touch on screen then it is correct but you need to set the origin of the shape to the center of the shape.

Comment: Venom4992 no its not in the top left corner. The shape's y pos is 500 but the touch pos at the same place is 1500! So when i press at the shape shape goes to y 1500

Comment: That's weird. I haven't used sfml for mobile so there might be something different about how coords work on mobile

Answer (score 0):

a few weeks i had the samd problem
Your Rectangle needs a FloatRect

```
sf::FloatRect shapeRect = shape.getGlobalBounds;
```

Then you have to use mapPixelToCoords in the while(window.isOpen()); loop

```
sf::Vector2i pixelPos = sf::Touch::getPosition(0, window);
sf::Vector2f worldPos = window.mapPixelToCoords(pixelPos);
```

Then you use both things with contains

```
if(shapeRect.contains(worlPos))
{

// type your stuff in

}
```

Now the Touch have to work only in the Shape, hope this help you